# Angular factory keep returned undefined

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, factory

My Angular factory keep return unddefined, below are two snippets that I am trying.

This is my **geoLocationService.js**

```
myApp.factory('geoLocationService', function () {

return {
    getMyGeolocation: function  () {

        var options = {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 5000,
            maximumAge: 0 };

        var x = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function success(pos) {
            return pos.coords;
        }, function error(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }, options);
    }
}
});
```

and this is my **controller.js**

```
myApp.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, geoLocationService){

$scope.shareThePost = function(){
    geoLocationService.getMyGeolocation().then(function(data){
        console.log(data)
    });
}
});
```

Comment: Can you show the exact error in your console?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: I post answer please try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning the promise. Every `.then()` relies on a promise being returned.

Add:

```
return x;
```

To the end of the `getMyGeolocation` function. And better yet, since you're not using the `x` anywhere else - you can return straight away:

```
return navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(....)
```

**EDIT:** Looks like the [getCurrentPosition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) does not return a promise, so you can't chain `.then()` on it. Instead, you need to wrap it with promise yourself to achieve what you want:

```
myApp.factory('geoLocationService', function ($q) {

return {
    getMyGeolocation: function  () {

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        var options = {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 5000,
            maximumAge: 0 };

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function success(pos) {
            deferred.resolve(pos.coords);
        }, function error(err) {
            console.log(err);
            deferred.reject(err);
        }, options);

        return deferred.promise;
    }
}
});
```

Comment: still not working, same error keep shwoin up in the console

Comment: @AmmarAlnaimat Good :)

Answer (score 0):

Because getMyGeolocation() function from factory is not returning anything. You have to add

```
return x;
```

from function. Because your promise is returning data to factory But your factory is not returning data to controller.

Comment: not work for me, same error keep show up in the console

Answer (score 0):

```
myApp.factory('geoLocationService', function () {
    return {
        getMyGeolocation: function() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                var options = {
                    enableHighAccuracy: true,
                    timeout: 5000,
                    maximumAge: 0 };

                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                    pos => resolve(pos.coords), 
                    err => reject(err),
                    options
                );
            };
        },
    };
});
```